# Foreach break and continue in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, break

I am facing an problem. I have built a `foreach` loop in PHP:

```
 <?php $show = false; ?>
 <?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
```

But I want to echo the first 20 items and continue with the following 16 items.

I have managed to make it to do a break after 20 items but I am not getting the following 16 items ( starting from nr 21 ).

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php $show = false; ?>
<?php $i = $item->id = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
<?php if(++$i > 20) break; ?>
```

If I set `$i` to `'21'` it still echos item 1 and so on.

### Solution  ## Thanks to @dhavald

```
<?php $show = false; ?>                                   
<?php foreach (array_slice ($this->items, 0, 20) as $item) : ?>
```

By placing an `array_slice` in the foreach you can control the items you want show. 
So on the next div i want to show item 21 to 36, the only thing i had to change was the 0 and 20 into , 20, 36

To clarify what I am looking for, I have three divs where I want to echo some items onto it. If an user collapse a div on the first there will appear the first 20 items and if a user clicks div2 the next 16 items will appear.

How can I correct this code to make that happen?

As i forgotten to mention, the solutions you bring on helped me really to understand the process but as i used a component generator for Joomla 3.1 there is one row of code that make it a little bit more complex to call the first 20 and second 16 items.

Directly after the foreach loop there is this line of code

```
if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()>authorise('core.edit.own',' com_ncitycatemus.vraagantwoordtoevoegen.'.$item->id))):

$show = true;
```

How can i manage it than with the loop ? Or do you suggest another way?

Thanks in advance! Really helped me to understand the loop!!

Answer (score 9):

`break` breaks out of and stops a loop. `continue` skips the rest of the code in the loop, and jumps to the next iteration.

Using `break` and `continue` is in my opinion the wrong approach here. I'd simply use two for loops:

```
$keys = array_keys($this->items);
$keysLength = count($keys);

echo '<div id="div1">';
for ($i = 0; $i < min($keysLength, 20); $i++) {
    echo $this->items[$keys[$i]];
}
echo '</div>';

if ($keysLength >= 20) {
    echo '<div id="div2">';
    for ($i = 20; $i < min($keysLength, 36); $i++) { //36 being 20 + 16
        echo $this->items[$keys[$i]];
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**Note**: This will work with any amount of items in `$this->items`. If it's under 20, it'll simply skip the next 16, and if it's above 36, it'll simply ignore the rest.

Comment: +1 for checking the actual length of `$this->items`. I was too lazy for that :D

Comment: Thanks! It gives a great view on the possible solution! But im facing another 'problem', i used a component generator, saved me lots of work on development of this component wich im trying to build on Joomla 3.1. so what i'm facing, directly after the foreach loop <?php if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.own','com_ncts.vraagantwoordtoevoegen.‌​'.$item->id))): $show = true;

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `break;` use `continue;`

Answer (score 2):

you can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get a part of $this->items array and assign it into 3 different variables and loop over them separately.

```
$itemsDiv1 = array_slice($this->items, 0, 20);  // gives first 20 items
$itemsDiv2 = array_slice($this->items, 20, 16); // gives next 16 items
```

and so on..

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $i = 0; ?> 

<!-- first group -->
<div>

<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?> 
<?php
/**
 * Check if count divided by 20 has no remainder
 */
if ( (++$i % 20) == 0 ): ?>

</div>
<!-- start new group -->
<div>

<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>

<!-- end last group -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stockNotNull = StockDetail::where('sku', 10101001)
            ->where('stock_quantity', '>', 0)->get('stock_id', 'stock_quantity');
        $toSell = 14;
        // decrements just once for each $stockNotNull
        foreach ($stockNotNull as $product) {
            if ($toSell < 1) {
                return;
            }
            $product->decrement('stock_quantity');
//            $product->stock_quantity--; returns with a null
//            dump($product->stock_quantity);
            $product->save();
            $toSell--;
//            dump($toSell);
            if($product->stock_quantity === 0) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

This is what I got so far, decrementing in the usual manner i.e $variable-- gives me a null value, $product->decrement('stock_quantity') subtracts 1 on each run, even if the stock_quantity field is far greater than the $toSell variable. The logic is there in my head, I'm just having trouble taking the quantity from the current item and moving on to the next only when the stock_quantity is 0.

Answer (score 0):

example for continue; and break; with Foreach Loop

```
$arr = [1=>"apple",2=>"banana",3=>"orange",4=>"grapes",5=>"lichi"];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  if ($k == 2) {
    continue;
  }
  if ($k == 5) {
    break;
  }
  echo "$k: $v <br>";
}
```

Output:

```
1: apple
3: orange
4: grapes
```